# Setup qtcreator using Microsoft Enterprise WDK

Tags: qt, qt-creator, wdk

I'm trying to setup qtcreator using Microsoft Enterprise WDK.
I want to build MSVC and UWP apps, but I do not want to install MS VisualStudio.

Does anyone know howto setup debugger cdb, c and c++ compiler, ... for qtcreator. Since MS EWDK is unzipped in a folder like C:\Dev qtcreator cannot auto-detect it.

I also flipped through the QT documentation, but it is confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

I still have no solution to integrate EWDK into qtcreator.
But there is an alternative to install a "minimum" Microsoft environment for qtcreator:

1. Install the Visual Studio Build-Tools, which is new as of 2017 and only select the build-tools for C++
2. Install only the debugger from Windows SDK